# WordPress Post Excerpt in a Slider

Tags: php, wordpress, post, slider

I want to create a slider but i can't get the post excerpt working. The title and permalink are working but the excerpt won't show... here is my code:

```
// Args
                        $args = array(
                            'cat' => $categories,
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'posts_per_page' => $amount,
                        );
                        // Our incrementing counter, leave this set to 0
                        $counter = 0;
                        // Query the posts based off of the parameters in the $args variable
                        $bs_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
                        // Our calculated limit of how many posts we have to work with, don't change this
                        $bs_posts_limit = count( $bs_posts->posts ) - 1;
                        // How many posts to display in each slide of the SlideDeck
                        $per_page = !empty($this->options['per-slide']) ? $this->options['per-slide'] : '2';
                        // Add "active" class to 1st slider item
                        $j=1;   

        // Carousel/Slider Html
                echo    "$tab<div" . (!empty($this->options['id']) ? ' id="slider-' . trim($thesis->api->esc($this->options['id'])) . '"' : '') . ' class="carousel slide'. (!empty($this->options['c-type']) ? ' ' . trim($thesis->api->esc($this->options['c-type'])) : '') .''. (!empty($this->options['class']) ? ' ' . trim($thesis->api->esc($this->options['class'])) : '') . "\" data-ride=\"carousel\">\n".
                        "$tab<h2 class=\"text-shadow\">". stripslashes($this->options['intro']) ."</h2>\n".
                        "$tab<div class=\"carousel-inner\">\n";
                    ?> 
                    <?php foreach( $bs_posts->posts as $bs_post ): ?>               
                    <?php
                        // Variables
                        $slide_number = floor( $counter / $per_page ) + 1;
                        $slide_mod = $counter % $per_page;
                        $bs_post_ID = $bs_post->ID;
                        $bs_post_title = get_the_title( $bs_post_ID );
                        $bs_post_link = get_permalink( $bs_post_ID );
                        $bs_post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $bs_post_ID );
                    ?>
                        <?php if( $slide_mod == 0 ): ?>
                        <div class="item <?php if($j <= 1) {echo 'active';} ?>">  
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="single">
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $bs_post->ID )) the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'title' => "#htmlcaption") ) ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $bs_post_link; ?>"><?php echo $bs_post_title;?></a> 
                        <?php echo $bs_post_excerpt; ?>             
                        <a href="<?php echo $bs_post_link; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="float:right;">Read More</a>                
                        </div>
                        <?php if( $slide_mod == ( $per_page - 1 ) || $counter == $bs_posts_limit ): ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php $counter++; $j++;?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?
                echo    "$tab</div>\n".
                        "$tab</div>\n"; 
                ?>
        <?
```

I want to create a slider based on bootstrap carousel plugin. Actualy i want to appear 2-3 or more posts per slide as you see and I succeded that but the slide only shows the post title and the post permalink. The excerpt and image won't work so please help me

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the docs, I see that get_the_excerpt() does not take a post id parameter. It must be used within the lop.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt

If you want to get the excerpt outside of the loop, you will have to get the full content of the post and truncate it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for help. I've managed to get it working. Thanks again.